# Jquery Cycle pause/resume: not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

Please take a look at this page: http://thaispa.inigowebdesign.co.uk/

Notice the slideshow rapidly looping through the images. Try clicking the black pause button. Notice it slows the animation but doesn't stop it?

Why??

Here is my Javascript, very simple using the in-built pause/resume methods as per the documentation:

```
$(".slide-ctrls").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("paused")){
        $(".slide-frame").cycle("resume");
        $(this).removeClass("paused");
    }else{
        $(".slide-frame").cycle("pause");
        $(this).addClass("paused");         
    }
});
```

Same problem in FF, Chrome & IE.

Comment: I'm looking over your code now but the first thing I notice is you need to load jQuery before your bootstrap js file. That's why you're getting an error in the console.

Comment: OK, thanks. I've changed it. Still the same problem though. I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's the answer: the 'lite' version does not support pause/resume commands. Once I replaced it with the [full Cycle 2 plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/download/), it worked fine.

(Weirdly though, attempting to call these commands on the lite version still interferes with it as I described above)